# scrollview with floating linearlayout will not scroll

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

Here is my gui xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:padding="5dip" android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblName" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/label_name"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nameLayout">
                <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chkName"></CheckBox>
                <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dip" android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dip"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblPhone" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/label_phone"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/lstPhone"></LinearLayout>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblEmail" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/label_email"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lstEmail"></LinearLayout>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblAddress" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/label_address"></TextView>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lstAddress"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" android:id="@+id/commandLayout">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnToClipBoard" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="To ClipBoard"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnCancel" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The LinearLayout id: commandLayout stays nicely at the bottom of the window. But the LinearLayout id: contentLayout won't scroll. If I move the commandLayout inside the scrollView everything scrolls. That isn't what I want though. I want to see the buttons no matter how long the contentLayout is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent most the day on this... Thanks.

**Edit:** Thanks for all of the responses. Changing from a FrameLayout to a RelativeLayout and setting the commandLayout align parent bottom and the scrollview align parent top was the solution that worked best.

Comment: If it helps I am using a layoutInflater to add items when the activity is created...

Comment: Just a guess: set the height of `ScrollView` to `wrap_content` and add a `weight=1`. And why do you need `gravity` `bottom|right` in the `commandLayout` with the width `fill_parent`? mb just `bottom` would be enough?

Comment: thanks for your response, I have tried what you suggested and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am using `HorizontalScrollView` rather than using `ScrollView`


        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/Scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="15dip">
          <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/View">
          </LinearLayout>
         </HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: put more items and remove all unnecessary properties. put lots of elements so that It can scroll. just an idea.

Comment: Just an idea : Why dont you use Custom ListView for this ?.If you have more than one items ?.. And again you can fix your buttons (id:commandLayout) as harism told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the base layout namely "frameLayout" into a relative layout.

I do this so that the "commandLayout" will be below of the "scrollView".
It doesn't make sense if the things you're going to show is hidden behind the "commandLayout"

I've added the alignParentBottom on "commandLayout".
I've also added layout_above="@+id/commandLayout" over at the "scrollView"

this is the working xml and yes it does scroll =)

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/commandLayout"
>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
        >
            <CheckBox 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chkName">
            </CheckBox>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20dip">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/lstPhone">
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/lstEmail"
        >
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/lstAddress">
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LongText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="This is a super long text that will hopefully cover the whole screen so as the scroll will work."
        >
        </TextView>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AnotherLongText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="This is another super long text to show that the scrolling will work even more!"
        >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#737754"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/commandLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToClipBoard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="To ClipBoard"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't forget your closing tag though... Thanks

Comment: =) it wasn't caught in the code box. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary to use FrameLayout? If I understood your goal correctly maybe RelativeLayout did what you're expecting;

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/commandLayout" ... />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/commandLayout"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now after I noticed you want "commandLayout" to float over ScrollView, it might be possible using RelativeLayout also if you align both elements to parent bounds. But this is something I can't verify at the moment - and especially don't know if it works any better compared to using FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not understand what the problem is fully, but here goes... I tried the layout file you have put up, and found that the bottom of the list is hidden behind the two buttons. So I added the following to the ScrollView widget, and it seemed fine.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
```

But, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, it scrolls. I added some CheckBoxes to the list to have it longer than a page.